# how to encrypt password provided and compare with Database data in Oauth 2.0 to get access token?

Tags: spring-boot

Actually i am using basic authentication in postman and provide client id and secret to get basic authentication key.Then i have provided  username,password and grant type to get access token.since my password is encrypted and stored in my DB.I have to pass encrypted password to get access token.Is there any way to encrypt my passed password to compare for authorization and get access token.

Comment: Your question is not really clear. The Basic scheme always requires a username and pass which in essence to create the Token – as you call it – by base64-encoding the string `<username>:<password>`. What is now your question in regards to DB?

Comment: for AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer

Comment: Aah, okay you are trying to implement an OAuth server. But still I'm not sure where you get stuck and what did you tried so far?